# Tensorboard not able to display all summaries

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

Since yesterday my Tensorboard doesn't display my scalar values anymore. In particular, I have 4 different scalar summaries but only one of them is displayed. I have tried to inspect the content of my summaries directory and seems that the Tensorboard is able to detect all my summaries. The strange thing is that yesterday was working smoothly.

At the moment I'm executing the Tensorboard in this way:

```
tensorboard --logdir=summaries/ --host=127.0.0.1 --inspect
```

And the result is the following:

````
======================================================================
Processing event files... (this can take a few minutes)
======================================================================

Found event files in:
summaries/hseq2seq_300_512_1024_1024
summaries/hseq2seq_300_1024_2048_2048
summaries/hseq2seq_300_256_512_512
summaries/hseq2seq_300_128_256_256

These tags are in summaries/hseq2seq_300_512_1024_1024:
audio -
histograms -
images -
scalars
   agent_rewards_summary
   decoder_loss_summary
tensor -
======================================================================

Event statistics for summaries/hseq2seq_300_512_1024_1024:
audio -
graph
   first_step           0
   last_step            0
   max_step             0
   min_step             0
   num_steps            1
   outoforder_steps     []
histograms -
images -
scalars
   first_step           0
   last_step            999999
   max_step             999999
   min_step             0
   num_steps            1000000
   outoforder_steps     []
sessionlog:checkpoint -
sessionlog:start -
sessionlog:stop -
tensor -
======================================================================

These tags are in summaries/hseq2seq_300_1024_2048_2048:
audio -
histograms -
images -
scalars
   agent_rewards_summary
   decoder_loss_summary
tensor -
======================================================================

Event statistics for summaries/hseq2seq_300_1024_2048_2048:
audio -
graph
   first_step           0
   last_step            0
   max_step             0
   min_step             0
   num_steps            1
   outoforder_steps     []
histograms -
images -
scalars
   first_step           0
   last_step            999999
   max_step             999999
   min_step             0
   num_steps            1000000
   outoforder_steps     []
sessionlog:checkpoint -
sessionlog:start -
sessionlog:stop -
tensor -
======================================================================

These tags are in summaries/hseq2seq_300_256_512_512:
audio -
histograms -
images -
scalars
   agent_rewards_summary
   decoder_loss_summary
tensor -
======================================================================

Event statistics for summaries/hseq2seq_300_256_512_512:
audio -
graph
   first_step           0
   last_step            0
   max_step             0
   min_step             0
   num_steps            1
   outoforder_steps     []
histograms -
images -
scalars
   first_step           0
   last_step            999999
   max_step             999999
   min_step             0
   num_steps            1000000
   outoforder_steps     []
sessionlog:checkpoint -
sessionlog:start -
sessionlog:stop -
tensor -
======================================================================

These tags are in summaries/hseq2seq_300_128_256_256:
audio -
histograms -
images -
scalars
   agent_rewards_summary
   decoder_loss_summary
tensor -
======================================================================

Event statistics for summaries/hseq2seq_300_128_256_256:
audio -
graph
   first_step           0
   last_step            0
   max_step             0
   min_step             0
   num_steps            1
   outoforder_steps     []
histograms -
images -
scalars
   first_step           0
   last_step            999999
   max_step             999999
   min_step             0
   num_steps            1000000
   outoforder_steps     []
sessionlog:checkpoint -
sessionlog:start -
sessionlog:stop -
tensor -
======================================================================
```
````

In the following you can find some details about my configuration:

- Operating system: MacOS High Sierra (latest update)
- Tensorflow version: 1.4.0
- Python version: 3.6.3

I have tried with all the browsers that I have namely: Chrome Canary, Firefox and Safari. The result is always the same.

Do you have any ideas? Even if it is not possible to use the Tensorboard at the moment, it will be fine to export this data to CSV. How can I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to display 4 different records as you can see in:

```
Found event files in:
summaries/hseq2seq_300_512_1024_1024
summaries/hseq2seq_300_1024_2048_2048
summaries/hseq2seq_300_256_512_512
summaries/hseq2seq_300_128_256_256
```

This should be either of your 4 subfolders.
Try using something like `tensorboard --logdir=summaries/hseq2seq_300_512_1024_1024 --host=127.0.0.1 --inspect` instead.

As for the 4 scalars you have defined your inspect result does not agree. There are 6 scalars in 1st, 2nd and 4th subfolder and only 2 in the 3rd. So, there is some inconsistency in what you expect and what you get.

Did you intend to use multiple event files (in different subfolders)? Is that you meant about "4 different scalar summaries"?

Comment: Actually, seems that it's just the Tensorboard terribly slow in visualising them. How is it possible? Is there any way to speed up the loading process?